# Xcode 6 iOS Simulator does not remember app settings

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, ios-simulator, iphone-6

I just installed Xcode 6.0.1 (coming from Xcode 5.1.1) and tried to run my iOS app on iPhone 6 simulator for the first time. It builds and runs, but I cannot change its settings. I use `NSUserDefaults` for my settings. Each time I change settings, go back to the list of settings and then select my app's settings again, they are set according to the default settings.

When I tried to figure out why this could happen I noticed that changing settings of the standard iOS app Maps does not work either. I cannot change the distance setting from miles to kilometers. This happens with fresh iOS Simulator settings (I "Reset Content and Settings" several times) when simulating iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in iOS 8.0 in the simulator.  The only workaround at this time is to set the preferences from the command line using the defaults command line tool.

```
defaults write ˜/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<UDID>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<App UUID>/Library/Preferences/...
```

You also need to find the relevant UDID.

Comment: Did this work? I copied the plist file from iOS 7 device version into the relevant folder and still no change for me.

Comment: This is terrible. Should be fixed as quickly as possible. You guys bit a little too much with this release of both developer tools and the OS itself. Another 3-4 months (aka "8.1") should have been allotted to have a much more stable product. Hardware sales be damned, for once!

Comment: i complete with this line of code to find name devices and relevant UDID. `find . -name 'device.plist' | xargs cat`

Comment: There's no need for that.  Just run 'xcrun simctl list'

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been fixed in Xcode 6.1 so consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, too. It seems that the settings file is not saved at all.

```
˜/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[GUID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[GUID]/Library/Preferences
```

is empty.

I've tried to use plist file from 7.1 simulator, but without any luck.

Downloading iOS 7.1 Simulator through XCode -> Preferences -> Download allowed me to save the settings, but that just for iOS 7.1.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But iPhone 6 requires iOS 8, doesn't it? So I can't test my app for iPhone 6 and/or iOS 8.